"MATRIX-WISE" multiplication
I am using a linnear application with a shape of Mx3x3. I want to apply it into a vector of Mx3x1. And obtain a final result of Mx3x1.
Using a loop in which I iterate through M is quite easy but may be inefficient. How can I solve it in a more efficient way?
Thx

In general you can use NumPy for linear algebra in Python, for example in this case numpy.matmul
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> b = np.arange(3)
>>> b
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> np.matmul(a,b)
array([ 5, 14, 23])


Yes, I was doing it before. But my problem is that having Nx3x3 and Nx3x1, making a loop is quite inefficient and there might be another way to do it in a more efficient way.

Can you please add some more details to your question? For example show an example input and your expected output? And if you were already using NumPy but did not achieve the output please share your attempt so we can see if there are any mistakes.

Sorry for that initial post being empty of information. I found the solution. I was initially iterating through my matrix in the third axis and then multiplying the matrix by a row of the vector. Here, you get an example of what I did before; I have to modify it slightly to have the same functionality.

indices = 57

vectors = np.random.randn(57,3)

result_vector = np.zeros((57,3))

for i in range(0,indices):
    #It has a complex way to compute it, so I leave it like random in this post
    R_inv = np.random.randn(3,3)
    #Here I apply a mask in order to select which rows I am applying the R_inv linnear application
    selected_vector = np.array(vectors[i,:]).reshape(1,3)
    result = np.array([ np.matmul(R_inv, np.transpose((selected_vector[j,:]))) for j in range(0,np.size(selected_vector,0)) ])
    result_vector[i] = result
    


But this was a time-consuming solution, with too many loops for many operations. So I decided to use np.einsum.
R_inv_vector = np.random.randn(3,3,57)
vectors = np.random.randn(57,3)

result_vector = np.einsum('kij,kj->ki', R_inv_vector, vectors)

In this way, I am avoiding using loops and doing it more efficiently.
I found this post very useful to understand how einsum works:
